# Google Play: We found Ad SDKs in your application but not using any ad sdk in code

Tags: android, ads

In my application not using `AD SDK` but google giving me warning as We found Ad SDKs in your application in gradle file also I am specifying particular service like API `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'` instead of the entirety of Play Services. But in manifest one code is there like

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

following is my gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"


defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding{
    enabled true
}

compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
api 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha06'
api 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-beta01'
api 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
api 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha04'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

api 'com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'


implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0"
```

}

because of this is it giving warning?

Comment: Post your gradle file code

Comment: maybe some of your third party library is using google ads dependency. check with dependency tree

Comment: ok it means its not related to com.google.android.gms.version ?